# Find The Equation

Tags: calculus

**This is the question:**

Find the equations of the tangent lines to the curve $y = x − \frac 1x + 1$ that are parallel to the line $x − 2y = 3$.

There are two answers: 1) smaller y-intercept; 2) larger y-intercept

**The work:**

The slope of the line is (1/2).

$y' = ((x + 1) - (x - 1))/(x + 1)^2 = 2/(x + 1)^2 = 1/2$

=> $(x + 1)^2 = 4$

=> $(x + 1) = 2$ and $ x + 1 = -2$

=> $x = 1$ and $x = -3$

At $x = 1$, $y = (x - 1)/(x + 1) = 0$

The equation of the tangent is $y/(x - 1) = (1/2)$

=> $2y = x - 1$

=> $x - 2y - 1 = 0$

At $x = -3$,$ y = (x - 1)/(x + 1) = -4/-2 = 2$

The equation of the tangent is $(y - 2)/(x + 3) = (1/2)$

=> $2y - 4 = x + 3$

=>$ x - 2y + 7 = 0$

Comment: I think its wrong but 1/2x+3/2 and 1/2x+7/2.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? (This is what barak manos is getting at. Show these things *in your question*.)

Comment: Hint $y=x-x^{-1}+1 $ Now differentiate.

Answer (score 2):

Two lines are parallel if they have the same slope, and the slope of a tangent line to a curve is the value of the derivative of the curve's function at that point. Therefore, follow this strategy.

1) Find the slope of the given line.

2) Find the derivative of the function defining the curve.

3) Set those expressions equal to each other and solve. This gives you the $x$-coordinate(s) of the intersection point(s) of the curve and the desired tangent line(s).

4) Find the $y$-coordinate for each $x$-coordinate you got in step 3.

5) Use the slope (from step 1) and the point(s) (from step 3) to find the equation(s) of the tangent line(s).

Answer (score 1):

there are no points on the graph of $y = x - \frac1x + 1$ has a tangent that is parallel to $x - 2y = 3.$

i will explain why.

you will get a better idea of the problem if you can draw the graph of $y = x - \frac1x + 1$ either on your calculator or by hand. the shape of the graph is called a hyperbola, similar looking to the rectangular hyperbola $y = \frac1x$ but here the asymptotes $x = 0$ and $y = x+1$ are not orthogonal. you will two branches one in the left half plane and the other in the right half plane. if you at the right branch, you can see that the slope starts very large positive fro $x$ very close to zero and positive, then gradually decreases to match the slope $1$ of the asymptote. that is the smallest slope on this graph. but the line you have $x - 2y = 3$ has slope $\frac12$ that is smaller than $1,$ the least slope on the graph.

here is how you see with calculus. taking the derivative of $y = x - \frac1x + 1$ you find $$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 + \frac1{x^2} \ge 1 \text{ for all} x. $$